# Issue in Fixing the position of Header and Footer in html

Tags: html, css

I have few grid view thumb images on index.html page in which Header and Footer are placed, as the grid images are scrolled even the Header and Footer gets scrolled, i had given Position:fixed; attribute still its not fixed. if i press some other page and come back then the header and footer are fixed, not at when the app gets starts.

css code

```
#Header { background: #8C001A; 
height: 36px; padding: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid    #3c3c3c; 
 z-index:101; 
 top: 0;
 bottom:80px;
 left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0; } 

#Footer { background: #8C001A;
 height: 30px;
 padding: 0; 
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000; 
  z-index:101; 
 bottom:0px;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0; 
bottom: 0;}
```

html code

```
 <div id="Header"> </div>

 <div id="Footer"> </div>
```

Comment: please update site link

Comment: similar to this link http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html#Gallery2.... but here header and footer are too scrolling, but in my app it shouldnt be @BipinKumarPal

Comment: Your CSS seems ok, need your detailed workaround as a working fiddle or url itself.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
body{
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
}
#Header {
   background: #8C001A; 
   height: 36px; padding: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid    #3c3c3c; 
   z-index:101; 
   top: 0;
   bottom:80px;
   left: 0;
   position: fixed;
   right: 0; 
} 

#Footer { 
  background: #8C001A;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000; 
  z-index:101; 
  bottom:0px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
}

#container{
  height:1600px;
  background-color:#00ffff;
}
#container1{
  height:1600px;
  background-color:#ffff00;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="Header"> </div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="Footer"> </div>
```

please try this code my side working all browser